# extract layers in a 1 layer psd file

Tags: wireframing

I have had some wire frames designed last year, and am now working with a developer whom I've shared the .psd file with and he says the file is one layer and needs the individual layers in order to manipulate the wire frames. Does anyone know how to revert the process to see the layers before he flattened them?

Comment: What caught my eye is that it seems you made the psd file but the dev told you the file is flattened. Shouldn't you know that if you made it?

Comment: Forgot my point there. It could be he used a third party app to open the psd and it didn't support layers. So maybe you should double check the file yourself.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I don't understand the question. Are you saying you flattened the layers, then gave the PSD to the developer?  If so, there's no way to get them back unless you kept a copy with the layers intact. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to extrapolate layers from a flat file automatically.

Once a file has been flattened the layers are gone for good. The *only* way to get layers back is via a *backup of the actual layered file*.